# Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error [errno 26])

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am working on xampp, windows 10

```
$account = \Stripe\Account::create([
            'country' => 'US',
            'type' => 'custom',
            'requested_capabilities' => ['card_payments', 'transfers'],
          ]);
         $file = \Stripe\File::create([
            'purpose' => 'identity_document',
            'file' => fopen('../images/3.jpg', 'r'),
          ], [
            'stripe_account' => 'acct_xxx',
          ]);
          $verification = \Stripe\Account::update(
            'acct_xxxxx',
            [
              'company' => [
                'verification' => [
                  'document' => [
                    'front' => $file->id,
                  ],
                ],
              ],
            ]
          );
```

When running it gives me the following error:

Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error [errno 26]: )

I tried updating TLS version, I unchecked 1.0 and 1.0 and just kept 1.2 enabled but it didn't help.

Comment: The error message suggests you contact Stripe support. Did you?

Comment: Is there more code prior to this that may help us help you? (whether direct or via require/include statements). For example, have you initiated Stripe and passed your secret key?

Comment: @ed2 Yes, but this identity document is only returning in error

Answer (score 0):

You should run the Stripe [reachability tool](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability) from the same machine to ensure you're able to communicate with the API.

If this is an intermittent error you can also configure [automatic retries](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#configuring-automatic-retries), though [idempotency keys](https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests) are recommended in this case.

Comment: The reachability tool is returning is the OK report and no it is not an intermittent error.